# SQL Server connection error when trying ro connect with local server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to connect to the local server

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to  (local).
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Comment: if you are going with localhost, it is likely to error. Try localhost/SQLExpress

Comment: ya i did it , its (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB , i found this through azure by coincidence i want to open azur cmd then it gaves me this (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB , i typed it and its work , my version is 2018